# How can I find string matches from an array of characters? ex. given a,n,t find string matches ant, an, tan in a word list table

Tags: php, mysql, string, string-matching

So far I have 27 tables in my database. One word table (a scrabble word list), and 26 association tables.

```
Table  Fields
================
word   [id,word]
a      [word_id,count]
b      [word_id,count]
...
z      [word_id,count]
```

I'm trying to figure out matching words given a string.

For example, if the given array is `a,n,t` I want to know: `ant, tan, at, ta, an, na`.

My current strategy is to explode each letter in the string and find the associated words that match all the letters.

For example:

```
SELECT word.word
FROM word, a, n, t
WHERE
    word.id = a.word_id OR
    word.id = n.word_id OR
    word.id = t.word_id
```

But this ends up printing all words that have a `a,n or t` in them.

And if I switch all the operators to AND, I'm stuck with only one match: `ant`.

Can you help me solve this riddle?

I'm also concerned with how to handle duplicate letters in the string.  I'm thinking that the `count` field in the letter association tables can help here.  If the word is `app`, the count will be 2 in the `p` association table.

Am I on the right track with the association tables or is there a better way?

I'm trying to handle this fairly efficiently in php/mysql. I'm aware there are others who have solved this riddle before in C, perl, java and the like.

Comment: can you explain how you did come up with what you want from `[a,n,t]`? - it looks like an arbitrary list of results for me

Comment: how did `pa` get in the result list for `a,n,t`?

Comment: Maybe you are better off with using regexes `^[ant]+$` – not sure how well that applies to your particular problem though.

Comment: @JanDvorak, LOL, you're right.  Edited.

Comment: @deathApril, yes, `a,n,t` is an arbitrary array of characters as an example.  It could just as easily have been `a,m,t`.  But the resulting words are actual words (in the Scrabble dictionary) that can be made from the same characters.  Essentially, I want to enter in a set of characters and quickly list all matching words that could be made from the given characters (using all or some of the characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a normalised approach, that would be:

```
wordLetters{
  INT wordID,
  CHAR[1] letter,
  INT count,
  PK(wordID, letter)
}

words{
  INT wordID PK,
  VARCHAR(255) word UNIQUE
}
```

but this approach has a serious problem in terms of performance - namely it needs a full table scan on the word table. I am going to assume that there are not too many letters and suggest this approach:

```
words{
  INT wordID PK,
  VARCHAR(255) word UNIQUE,
  INT cA KEY,
  INT cB KEY,
  ...
  INT cZ KEY,
  KEY (cE, cT, cA, cO, cI, cN),
  ...
}
```

A lookup query will be long but it will use indexes efficiently and it is generated by the PHP code anyways:

If the user has `[a,n,t]`, fetch the available words as:

```
SELECT word FROM words WHERE
   cA <= 1 AND cB = 0 AND cC = 0 AND ... AND cY = 0 AND cZ = 0
```

This query will (probably) use the "ETAOIN" index as not many words that don't need an 'E' exist.

At this point, performance depends on the choice of indexes available for the database only and you can always add more indexes as deemed useful (even at runtime).

---

On database indexes:

An ordinary index is just a sorted list of items with an appropriate tree built over the list, enabling efficient range lookup (get all elements from x to y).

An ordinary index is defined by its sorting order. The sorting order is: order by some column first, then on another one, then on another one... .

For example, the `[E,T,A,O,I,N]` index will have all words sorted: first all words that don't need an `E`, then all words that need one `E`, then all words that need two `E`... . The words that need the same amount of `E`s will be sorted: first all words that don't need a `T`, then all words that need it once, then all words that need two `T`s ... . Of the words that need the same number of `E`s and `T`s, those that don't need an `A` come first.

If the database is asked to fetch all words that don't need an `E` or a `T` and at most one 'X', it can use this index to fulfill the first two requirements, then check all words within the range `E=0, T=0`.

The particular choice, `ETAOIN` is based on the phrase [ETAOIN SHRDLU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ETAOIN_SHRDLU) which orders the twelve most frequent letters in the english language by their frequency - this means that if this index is used, it should filter out the largest possible amount of words.

You use the example `RSTLNE`. This index will/may get used when the player has no `R`s, or `S`s. Benchmarking the lookup may tell you how much time was saved by using each particular index.

You can use an [`EXPLAIN EXTENDED`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) query to see which indexes are considered and subsequently used for each particular query and how many rows are expected  to be filtered out. Ex.:

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED
  SELECT word FROM words
  WHERE cA=0 AND cB<=1 AND cC=0 AND ...
```

Comment: Interesting.  Can you explain more about the `KEY (cE, cT, cA, cO, cI, cN)` strategy?  Are those just popular letters?  And is this what you mean when you say I can add indexes as needed?  As in, add an `RSTLNE` key if those are also used frequently?

Comment: @Ryan Added an explanation about indexes.

Comment: Wow, this is great.  So simple and it works!  One last question.  I haven't been able to get the keys set for the multiple fields.  Can you help me with an `ALTER TABLE` query for ETAOIN to get this set up?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html. The syntax is `ALTER TABLE words ADD INDEX i_etaoin(cE, cT, cA, cO, cI, cN)` where `i_etaoin` is the index name. If you don't specify an index name, one will be generated.